# How to add ACL on OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap, access-control-list, ldif

I want to add an ACL for a sub organization on my OpenLDAP.

This is their ACL documentation:
https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html

I am using `ldapmodify` to update the ldap db on a running OpenLDAP instance.

This is the *ldif* file I have imported:

## vim ro_access.ldif

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {2}to dn.children="ou=users,dc=example,dc=com" by dn.exact="cn=workstation,ou=applications,dc=example,dc=com" read
```

#### I expect

- has `cn=workstation,ou=applications,dc=example,dc=com` to be able to read children under `ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`
- has `auth` to have the preceding default behavior.
- has `anonymous` to have the preceding default behavior.

#### I have

- `ldapwhoami` working with `cn=workstation,ou=applications,dc=example,dc=com`
- `ldapsearch` failing returning result `uid=someone,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com` with `cn=workstation,ou=applications,dc=example,dc=com`

**Edit**

I have tried to replace `olcAccess` `{1}` with `{2}` and `{2}` with `{1}`.

This is the full replaced ACL and it also does not work:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by dn="cn
 =admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by dn="cn=ropw,dc=example,dc=co
 m" read by anonymous auth by * none 
olcaccess: {1}to dn.children="ou=users,dc=example,dc=com" by dn
 .exact="cn=workstation,ou=applications,dc=example,dc=com" read
olcaccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by dn="cn=ro,dc=example,dc=com" read by dn="cn=ropw,dc=exam
 ple,dc=com" read by * none
```

Any Idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `by anonymous auth by * none` at the end of your ACL directive:

```
olcAccess: {1}to dn.children="ou=users,dc=example,dc=com" by dn
 .exact="cn=workstation,ou=applications,dc=example,dc=com" read
by anonymous auth by * none
```